# How do I get my code to loop?

Tags: ruby

im trying to get my code to loop (im very new to ruby)
I want to make the program loop when it doesnt. 
I am told that my code is very wrong, but is there anyway I can get it to loop anyways?

```
class Screen
  def clear
  end

  def pause
    STDIN.gets
  end
end

class Lottery

  attr_accessor :greeting, :register, :morereg, :goodbye, :lotterynumbers, :randomtwenty

  def initialize 
  end

  def say_greeting
    greeting = "\n\n\n\t\t ***Welcome to elGordo lottery!***\n\n" + 
    "\t\t      Press Enter to continue.\n\n\n"
    print greeting
  end

  def say_register
    register = "Type in the lotterynumber you want to register and then press Enter.\n\n"
    print register #nedenunder [@counter]
    Lotterynumbers1 << gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  def say_morereg
    morereg = "would you like to type in another lottery number? (y/n)\n"
    print morereg
    gets.chomp!
    if gets.chomp! == "y" then
      say_register
    else
      puts "\nThank you for the register.\n\n"
    end 
  end

  # def say_randomtwenty
  #   Lotterynumbers1 << << 20.times.map { rand(00000..99999).to_i }
  # end

  def say_goodbye
    goodbye = "\nThank you for the register.\n\n"
    print goodbye
  end
end

#main Script Logic

Lotterynumbers1 = []

Console_Screen = Screen.new
Hej = Lottery.new #starter nyt Lotteri object 

Hej.say_greeting 
Console_Screen.pause

Hej.say_register
Hej.say_morereg
puts Lotterynumbers1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got confused with conditional statement and looping thinking if user go on says yes(y), then it would be a kind of looping(executing the same procedure many times) by your code.

But its not

Comment: yeah i did, sorry about the "bad" post :) still new here and new to ruby.